# Perfluorobutanesulfonic acid (PFBS) Safety and Toxicity

Tags: acid-base, safety, toxicity, surfactants

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with PFBS or PFOS (perflurooctane sulfonic acid)?
I am thinking about trying to purchase some of these fluorosurfactants in bulk in order to (hopefully) use as a solvent.  However, I have read that PFOS is now banned due to the bad effects on people's health and the environment.  However, they claim that PFBS is a little better (half like of ~1 month in humans compared to ~5.5 years).
So, I was wondering how terrible it would be to be dealing with the pure liquid on a daily basis, with the use of some gloves and a hood. The hood isn't great in terms of suction, but it's at least something. I should also add that the hood is of course open to the air, so there's moisture in the air. 
I do deal with chlorosulfonic acid in the hood pretty regularly, and it isn't a huge problem, although I'm not aware of HCl getting trapped in your system for extended periods of time either.
I also hope to be contacting these liquids with chlorosulfonic acid, where I hope that no reactions will occur, but I am not so great at chemistry so I don't know if that is a fair assumption.

I also noticed that they state in the Wikipedia article for [PFOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanesulfonic_acid) and [PFBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorobutanesulfonic_acid) that these substances are used in some consumer items.  So, if they are used in consumer items without degrading, how dilute do they have to be to not have strong acute or mild long term health effects?
I figure they would have to be pretty bad in order for 3M to ban PFOS, but I don't know if that was mainly in order to stop the mass use of them in consumer items.

[The MSDS for PFBS states that the LD50 for mice is 430 mg/kg, and it shouldn't be contacted with any moisture in air at all](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=US&language=en&productNumber=562629&brand=ALDRICH&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Faldrich%2F562629%3Flang%3Den)  While the [Chlorosulfonic acid MSDS states some similar, but more tame, statements about moisture, and it's LD50 in mice is 50mg/kg.](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/571024?lang=en&region=US)

So, I guess my main question is, has anyone used this substance in it's pure form in a normal hood type of environment?

Comment: "has anyone used this substance in it's pure form in a normal hood type of environment?" - Probably. "has anyone used this substance in it's pure form in a normal hood type of environment without long term adverse health impacts?"  - I think this is the question you are really asking. Please note that LD50 data is really only relevant for when all of your risk control measures have failed, which may be likely if your hood "isn't great in terms of suction, but it's at least something".

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I should have been more clear about the first question; obviously I know _someone_ has handled this stuff, but I was just seeing if anyone _on this site_ is familiar with the real use of the material.  For example, the technicians at my work deal with HF pretty regularly and they can speak about the real dangers of it, or simply say "it's not too bad if you don't get it on you" because they have more experience.
I'm just trying to figure out if I'm going to be in danger by opening it or if I have to spill it on me, etc.